# Why diodes are made up with semiconductor?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

I am little bit confuse about 'Why diodes are made of semiconductors'. I know the properties of semiconductor and also know the process of doping but still confuse to get the answer. Why the making of diode uses semiconductor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A diode is a circuit element that passes current (conducts) only in one direction and not in the other. It doesn't have to be made with a semiconductor. It can also be made with a vacuum tube. With today's manufacturing and material technology, using semiconductor materials is a simple method of making diodes. Today, silicon and germanium based semiconductors are used. Earlier in history, metal point contacts with materials such as uranium oxide were used in the early radio receivers.

Comment: semiconductor is use for making a diode because we can control its conductivity through doping ? Am I right ?

Comment: If you have time kindly clear my doubt. I am very thankful to you.

Comment: It's more than just conductivity, it has to do with the movement of electrons. Inside a silicon diode, a junction between P and N type silicon forms an internal electric field. The characteristics of this junction allow current to pass through in only one direction.

Comment: Point contact diodes are semiconductors, too.